# Android wear, Tizen Encryption

Tags: android, disk-encryption

Does Android Wear or Tizen for wearables offer hardware encryption? I have the Samsung Galaxy Gear S and I don't see an option, but was curious if it does it without any user intervention. I don't have any Android Wear watches, but was curious in buying one. I have the Apple Watch and I read that it does offer hardware encryption:

"Apple Watch implements hardware-encrypted storage and class-based protection
of files and keychain items, as described in the Data Protection section of this paper." [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)

Does anyone know? I can't seem to find anything on the internet. Just hacks security experts have done.

Comment: Someone please do a writeup of this article -- http://www.androidguys.com/2015/06/14/lg-and-samsung-smartwatches-leave-data-unencrypted/

Comment: @atdre that's actually the hacks I was referring to. That focuses on blue tooth encryption methods. What I was referring to is hardware encryption on the device.

Comment: @ pqsk : Ok great, that's what I thought but glad you clarified. Now on to an answer!

Comment: Well, I can't answer until someone reopens this question but check out these resources in the meantime -- http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2015ams/materials/Whitepapers/Hacking%20Tizen%20-%20The%20OS%20of%20Everything.pdf
-- http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2015ams/materials/D2T2%20-%20Ajin%20Abraham%20-%20Hacking%20Tizen%20-%20The%20OS%20of%20Everything.pdf

Comment: To roughly summarize, Wear and Tizen don't do any full-disk encryption, so encryption must be provided by the app, preferably at the transport layer to a TLS-based service (and then stored securely on a server). Three Wear devices can currently be rooted, and as such, strace, gdb, and other memory-dumping, hooking, and software/process tracing/debugging tools can be leveraged to read data at the system-call, kernel, or other userspace layer. Libraries can be shimmed and methods/functions can be clobbered.

Comment: Cool thanks @atdre. Sorry about the confusion. I did update my question to specify the type of encryption. Didn't realize I did not write that, even though it's closed now. So if it gets re-opened you can answer that and I can mark as the answer.

Comment: @ pqsk : Thank you. Here also is a better analysis on Android Wear -- https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2015/05/22/android-wear-security-analysis/